# How would speakers work with dual Thunderbolt displays?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, external-display, thunderbolt

If I connect a Thunderbolt MacBook Pro to two Thunderbolt displays, would it output the sound from four speakers, i.e. 49 watts x2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sound would only come from one at a time](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1236263). You can pick which one in the Sound Options.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default, to only one display. You can create [an aggregate device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3956) that uses both displays, but you cannot duplicate an output channel. All you can do is configuring the couple of the four available speakers you want to use.

You can instead create a "Multi-output" device; then it would play through all the four speakers. Stereo is a bit weird though. (You can include your MBP's speakers for maximum lollery.) Annoyingly, you can't adjust volume easily, though.